Running `docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up` doesnt work when trying to install apache superset
Trying to install Apache Superset.
I am trying to do docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up . I get the following output
unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
Also when running docker compose up , i get
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.

please add system architecture(ubuntu/debian/rasberry-pi) and docker version you using

Have you in fact installed Compose?
